# Why am i not able to redirect to my get router when fetched with a post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, redirect

**profile.ejs**

```
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <h1>Hello, <span><%= user.name %></span>!<hr> How are you doing?</h1>
        <!-- <form action="/users/logout" method="POST"></form> -->
            <button onclick="logout()">LOGOUT</button>
        <!-- </form> -->
    </div>

    <script>

        var userToken = document.cookie.replace('jwt=','')
        // console.log(document.cookie)
        // console.log(userToken)

        function logout()
        {
            fetch('/users/logout', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userToken
                },
                redirect: 'follow'
            })
            // .then(res => res.json())
            .then(response=>{
                    if (response.redirected) {
                        window.location.href = response.url;
                    }
            })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
        }
        
    </script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
app.post('/users/logout' ,async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        req.user.tokens = req.user.tokens.filter((token)=>{return token.token!=req.token})
         await req.user.save()
        // res.status(200).send({message:'Logged Out Successfully!'})
        console.log('Logged Out Successfully!')
        res.redirect('/')
  
    }catch(e){
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index')
    console.log('ok')
})
```

Surprisingly, i am getting the message 'ok' from the second router. However i am not redirected to it! The url does not change!
Someone pls help me with this. I am stuck here since very long!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `window.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`

Comment: i dont know how but i rebooted my pc only to find that the programme worked very perfectly! However, can u explain me why did u suggested that?

Comment: `pathname` (how it suggests) is only to path address, `href` is for the full URL domain + path